# How do i format string with comma delimited

Tags: java, python, jenkins-groovy, groovy-console, groovy-eclipse

[please find the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWHi7.png) I have a string like this : Hello,1,2 World,6,7 Home,10,11
I want my output as :
Hello World Home
1 6 10
2 7 11
Below is my code:
def a = "Hello,1,2 World,6,7 Home,10,11";
a=a.replace(',',"\n")
println(a)

Comment: Please format your code properly (hint: use the `{}` button). Screenshots of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow. Then fix the obvious syntax error.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a specific problem you ran into? Hint: Break the string up into an array using `array = a.split(",");`, then check which ones are numbers and sort it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do `string.split(',')` to get a list , and `' '.join(string.split(','))` to get a string of all these elements separated by a `' '`. This is very simple splitting, for more sophisticated parsing, use the `csv` module.

This answer is for Python. I don't know why you have both `java` and `python` as tags.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate that output logically as there is no (obvious) way to determine the order of the integers.

However, if you just want to isolate the words and integers then join them together in the order in which they were defined, then that can be done.

The tokens in your initial string are not just comma separated so the split technique suggested in previous answers won't work. You'll need to use the regex module thus:

```
import re

d = 'Hello,1,2 World,6,7 Home,10,11'
w = ''
n = ''
for token in re.split(',| ', d):
    try:
        int(token)
        n += token + ' '
    except ValueError:
        w += token + ' '

print(w + n.rstrip())
```

The output of this will be: Hello World Home 1 2 6 7 10 11

Comment: Note that you can do it logically by attempting to parse the strings to integers and simply add/move valid integers to the end of the array.

Comment: Please review the original question with respect to the input data and output requirement and note that the integer tokens appear in the output in a different order to the input

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Hello,1,2 World,6,7 Home,10,11";
    
    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer sb3 = new StringBuffer();
    String[] ar = a.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if(ar[i].contains(" ") && isNumeric(ar[i].split(" ")[0])){
            sb1.append(ar[i].split(" ")[0]+" ");
            sb2.append(ar[i].split(" ")[1]+" ");
        } else if(isNumeric(ar[i])){
            sb3.append(ar[i]+" ");
        } else{
            sb2.append(ar[i]+" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb2+""+sb3+""+sb1);
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
    if (strNum == null) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        double i = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

you should try this.